# Powershell - What does if($variable) test for?

Tags: powershell

In Powershell, what does `if($variable)` test for?  Is this testing if the variable is set, is null, is true, or something else?

Comment: It depends on the type of the variable. It's a common thing in Python and JavaScript as well, and in general things which become $true in this context are known as 'truthy' and things which become $false in this context are known as 'falsey' - although exactly what happens is different in different languages. In PowerShell - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/12/24/boolean-values-and-operators/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It tests whether the variable is true or whether a non-Boolean variable can be coalesced to true.  For example, each of these return false:

```
$var #uninitialized
$var = ""
$var = $false
$var = 0
```

Each of these return true:

```
$var = "something"
$var = $true
$var = 1 #or any non-zero number
```

Comment: Thank you, I inherited some code with this syntax and it seemed to be used to mean different things.  I'll mark this as answered when I'm able to.

Comment: "*It tests whether the variable contains something*" - not exactly; in PowerShell, an empty array is $false but an empty hashtable is $true. (Unlike Python where an empty dictionary is falsey).

Comment: This is a good answer but more specifically, it tests if something is `$true` or can be coalesced to `$true`. In other words, there's an implicit cast to `[bool]`, such that the conditional will use whatever the value of `[bool]$var` is. The details of which values evaluate to `$true` or to `$false` varies, as this answer points out and TessellatingHeckler expanded upon.

Comment: @briantist That's a better way to say it.  I've rephrased the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Powershell uses loose typing, and as a part of this any value can be used as a conditional expression. The logic of evaluating values to true or false (such values are often called "truthy" and "falsey") is in the [System.Management.Automation.LanguagePrimitives.IsTrue](http://blog.whatsupduck.net/2012/01/casting-objects-to-boolean-in.html) function. The logic is the following:

- `$null` evaluates to false.
- `$true` and `$false` have their usual meaning.
- A numeric value (int, double, decimal etc.) is truthy, if it is non-zero.
- A string is truthy, if it is non-empty.
- A switch parameter evaluates to true, if it has been supplied by the caller.

```
function Test 
{
   param ( [switch]$Option )
}

Test # $Option evaluates to false
Test -Option # $Option evaluates to true

# (Technically, $Option is not bool; it is of type SwitchParameter which, 
# for almost all intents and purposes, can be used interchangeably with bool.)
```

- A collection (implementing `IList`) uses the following logic: An empty collection is falsey; a collection with only one element evaluates to the truth value of its member; a collection with two or more elements is truthy.
- Anything else is truthy.

There are a couple of gotchas:

- The char type is not a numeric type. Indeed, `[System.Management.Automation.LanguagePrimitives]::IsTrue([char]0)` returns True (per the final clause); yet `if([char]0) { "Truthy" } else { "Falsey" }` returns "Falsey". I wasn't able to find the reason why this happens.
- As mentioned above, a collection with exactly one element is evaluated by evaluating its member. So what happens if you try to evaluate a collection which only contains itself (or a recursive or very deeply nested chain of collections, each with one element)? For science, you can test it:

```
$array = New-Object -TypeName System.Object[] 1 # $array = new object[1]
$array[0] = $array
if($array) { "Truthy" } else { "Falsey" }
```

(The answer is: it crashes the process with StackOverflowException.)

Comment: In Powershell Core `[System.Management.Automation.LanguagePrimitives]::IsTrue([char]0)` still returns true (though `[char]0` itself is still falsey), but an array containing itself no longer crashes the shell and is truthy.