# Powershell Custom Object Confusion

Tags: powershell

I was working on a script trying to output two different custom objects; one after another and was having problems, so to simplify, I stripped all the code down to just the minimum:

```
$beep = new-object -TypeName PSObject
$beep | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Entry1" -Value "beep1"
$beep | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Entry2" -Value "beep1"
$beep

$boop = new-object -TypeName PSObject
$boop | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Entry1" -Value "boop1"
$boop | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Entry2" -Value "boop1"
$boop
```

When I run this, it appears the objects are combined together.  When I do a get-member, it seems to just show one object.  Why?

In the code I am actually trying to finish, one object is a custom object like above, but the other it a selected.system.int32.  When I try to output one after the other only the first one outputs.  If I flip the order; same thing, the first object gets output.  What am I doing wrong / don't understand?

@JamesQ - I guess what is confusing me is when I do:

```
$beep = new-object -TypeName PSObject
$beep | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Entry1" -Value "beep1"
$beep | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Entry2" -Value "beep1"
$beep | get-member

$boop = new-object -TypeName PSObject
$boop | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Entry1" -Value "boop1"
$boop | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Entry2" -Value "boop1"
$boop | get-member
```

I get:

```
TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name        MemberType   Definition
----        ----------   ----------
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method       type GetType()
ToString    Method       string ToString()
Entry1      NoteProperty System.String Entry1=beep1
Entry2      NoteProperty System.String Entry2=beep1
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method       type GetType()
ToString    Method       string ToString()
Entry1      NoteProperty System.String Entry1=boop1
Entry2      NoteProperty System.String Entry2=boop1
```

I was trying to keep the question simple, but I think I've made it too ambiguous so...

I am trying to reuse some code:

```
function Get-NetworkConfig($computerName) {
  Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapter -Filter 'NetConnectionStatus=2' |
    ForEach-Object {
      $result = 1 | Select-Object Name, IP, MAC
      $result.Name = $_.Name
      $result.MAC = $_.MacAddress
      $config = $_.GetRelated('Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration') 
      $result.IP = $config | Select-Object -expand IPAddress
      $result
    }
}
```

then in the same script something like:

```
function Get-ComputerInfo($computerName) {
    $operatingSystem = Get-WMIObject -computername $computerName win32_operatingsystem
    $computerInfo = new-object -TypeName PSObject
    $computerInfo | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Computer Name" -Value ("$computerName")
    $computerInfo | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Operating System" -Value ("$operatingSystem.Caption")
    $computerInfo
}

$computerNames = $args
foreach ($computerName in $computerNames) {
    Get-ComputerInfo($computerName)
    Get-NetworkConfig($computerName)
}
```

Only the output from get-computerinfo is displayed, then a bunch of blank lines where get-networkconfig would have output.

If I reverse the order; only the first function gives output, the second only spits blank lines.

Why can't I just call two functions in sequence like this?

Comment: Much depends on how you are trying to display the objects.  I ran the code above and, as expected, got two different objects.  `Get-Member` only takes one object (at a time), so I don't understand your statement about "showing one object."

Try running different permutations of this to convince yourself that you have multiple objects:  `Write-Output "beep Entry1 = $($Beep.Entry1)"`

Comment: If you want to output both try doing `return $beep, $boop`

Comment: If you do an import-csv from data stored in a csv file,  you get an array of PSCustomObjects.  Off topic, but worth learning anyway.  You might want to fiddle around with making an array out of $beep and $boop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> When I do a `Get-Member`, it seems to just show one object.

`Get-Member` shows information about the *distinct* types in the collection of inputs, which means that the first occurrence of each type is reported on, with subsequent occurrences skipped.

In your case, *both* input objects are of type `[System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]`, so `Get-Member` will report just that *one* shared type.

For instance, `1, 2 | Get-Member` reports information about `System.Int32` *once*.

---

> one object is a custom object like above, but the other it a selected.system.int32. When I try to output one after the other only the first one outputs.

PowerShell's default output formatting defaults to implicit use of `Format-Table` for custom objects with up to 4 properties.

**If you output multiple objects that have *different types*, and the first object defaults to implicit `Format-Table` output, that first object's type *alone* determines *what properties (columns) to show* in the resulting table.**

- **Note**: If the first object's type happens to have *formatting data* associated with it (as reported by [`Get-FormatData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Get-FormatData)), subsequent objects *do* print, albeit invariably via implicit `Format-List` formatting.

**If subsequent objects do not have *any* of the same properties that the first object has, they simply print a blank line**; if they have *some* of the same properties, only those are printed; any *additional* properties are ignored.

**It is important to note that this is just a *display* problem**, however: all objects that were output are still present; if you send the output to another command for further processing instead of directly to the console, they'll all be there.

A simple example:

```
PS> [pscustomobject] @{ one = 1; two = 2 }, [pscustomobject] @{ three = 3 }
    
one two
--- ---
  1   2
```

Note how the 2nd custom object resulted in just a blank line, because it has neither properties `.one` nor `.two`.

You can **work around the problem by using *explicit* formatting commands applied to *each object*** to output:

```
PS> [pscustomobject] @{ one = 1; two = 2 }, [pscustomobject] @{ three = 3 } |
      ForEach-Object { Format-Table -InputObject $_ }

one two
--- ---
  1   2



three
-----
    3
```

The same approach as individual output commands:

```
[pscustomobject] @{ one = 1; two = 2 } | Format-Table
[pscustomobject] @{ three = 3 } | Format-Table
```

As [Mark Wragg's blog post](http://wragg.io/tilfmol1-the-powershell-pipeline) explains, **all output produced by a given script** - even across separate commands - is sent to the **same pipeline**.
(You can think of a command line submitted interactively as an implicit script.)

For a more **detailed discussion of how a mix of types in a single pipeline is handled in terms of display formatting**, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55504393/45375).

---

**Why using an explicit formatting command helps:**

By **explicitly piping to a `Format-*` cmdlet** (e.g, `[pscustomobject] @{ one = 1; two = 2 } | Format-Table`), you're actually sending *formatting objects* (various `[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.*]` types) to the pipeline, and PowerShell then effectively *passes them through* for display.

An alternative is to use a ***generic* workaround**: if you **pipe to `Out-Host`** instead (e.g., `[pscustomobject] @{ one = 1; two = 2 } | Out-Host`), in which case:

- you bypass the pipeline and print directly to the console (if you're running PowerShell in a regular console window),
- and the object's *default* formatting view is applied.

It is important to note that **these workarounds are suitable only for *display* purposes**, because the original objects are *lost* in the process:

- When you pipe to a `Format-*` cmdlet explicitly, you replace the original object with objects containing formatting instructions, which are useless for further processing.
- When you pipe to `Out-Host`, you send *nothing* to the script's pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$beep = new-object -TypeName PSObject
$beep | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Entry1" -Value "beep1"
$beep | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Entry2" -Value "beep1"
$beep | format-table

$boop = new-object -TypeName PSObject
$boop | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Entry1" -Value "boop1"
$boop | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Entry2" -Value "boop1"
$boop | format-table
```