# Using "Get-WmiObject" Twice in a script not working

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I am trying to run a simple script, which contains Logical Disk's FreeSpace and Size information, though the output of this is not what i am trying to accomplish.
I wont list the full script since it's irrelevant, I am going to list just these two commands.

**Here is the Script:**

```
    Get-WmiObject -Class win32_logicaldisk | select -Property Name , @{n='HDDs Total Size In GB';e={[math]::Round($_.size/1gb)}}


Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_logicalDisk | select -Property Name , @{n='HDDs FreeSpace';e={[math]::Round($_.FreeSpace/1gb)}}
```

**This is the Output:**

```
    Name HDDs Total Size In GB
---- ---------------------
C:                     111
D:                     932
E:                     932
C:                        
D:                        
E:
```

As you can see it leaves the Free space empty.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `$_.size` != `$_.FreeSpace`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's no particular reason to calling it twice you can get the free space in just one:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class win32_logicaldisk | select -Property Name , @{n='HDDs Total Size In GB';e={[math]::Round($_.size/1gb)}}, @{n='HDDs FreeSpace';e={[math]::Round($_.FreeSpace/1gb)}}
```

This is my output:

```
Name HDDs Total Size In GB HDDs FreeSpace
---- --------------------- --------------
C:                     146              6
E:                     205             35
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is really helpful now that i know how this works .

Still learning :) .

Answer (score 1):

[Fabian Mendez's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8056934/fabian-mendez) *bypasses* the problem by providing a *single-command* solution.

As for **your symptom**:

> As you can see it leaves the Free space empty.

No, it simply doesn't *print* the `HDDs FreeSpace` column *to the console* - though that column (properties by that name on the output objects) still exists, if you were to examine the output *programmatically*.

In short, **your *first* `Get-WmiObject ... | Select-Object` command *locks in* the display columns**, which are `Name` and `HDDs Total Size In GB`.

While the *second* command's output has a `Name` column, it lacks a `HDDs Total Size In GB` column, so no values show up for it - and the `HDDs FreeSpace` column is *ignored* altogether.

This behavior, which **relates to implicit use of the `Format-Table` output-formatting cmdlet**, is explained in detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45705068/45375) of mine.

**To force separate output formatting for each command, use `... | Out-Host` or `... | Format-*`** (formatting cmdlets such as `Format-Table`).

**Caveat**: **Do *not* do this if you need to process the output *programmatically***, because `Out-Host` *bypasses* PowerShell's success (data) output stream; while using `Format-*` cmdlets would still send data to the success stream, this data is no longer the *input* objects, but rather objects representing *formatting instructions*.

---

#### Simplified example:

```
PS> [pscustomobject] @{ one=1; two=2 }; [pscustomobject] @{ one=10; three=30 } 

one two
--- ---
  1   2
 10
```

Note how column `two` is blank for the 2nd object and its `three` column doesn't print at all, because only the *1st* output object's properties determined the output columns.

Through explicit use of `Out-Host` or a formatting cmdlet you can force the two commands to be formatted individually:

```
PS> [pscustomobject] @{ one=1; two=2 } | Out-Host; [pscustomobject] @{ one=10; three=30 } 

one two
--- ---
  1   2



one three
--- -----
 10    30
```

Note how each object's columns now show up, preceded by an object-specific header.

Comment: This is very helpful, I managed to make something work out of this and it worked just fine,  in fact this helped me with other scripts which i have a similar issue with, I appreciate it !