# Why is the output format changed when running two PowerShell commands in one line?

Tags: powershell, formatting

I'm getting unexpected results when executing two PowerShell commands separated by a semicolon. The output of the second command changes. If I run them in reverse order, I don't see the second command output.

Here I'm simply trying to get a time stamp and a list of groups a user belongs to in AD, as a one-liner.

If I run this line, i get the following output:

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership username | Select-Object name

name
----
Domain Users
CL-Inventory-Group
...
```

However if I run the following, this behavior changes:

```
get-date; Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership username | Select-Object name

Wednesday, April 3, 2019 2:31:35 PM

name : Domain Users


name : CL-Inventory-Group


...
```

Stranger yet, If i run the in reverse, meaning i say get-date after the first command, the date stamp never shows up after the groups are listed.

Am I improperly separating commands?

Comment: I think this has something to do with PowerShell's auto formatting of output in the console because if you change this to `$a = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership username | Select-Object name; $b = get-date`, both variables will have the proper data. It could be because `get-date` outputs in a non-table format while the other command outputs in table format. If you piped both to `Format-Table` or `Format-List` you can see both.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**tl;dr**:

Submitting multiple `;`-separated commands at the prompt (interactively) still sends their output to a *single* pipeline (you can think of each command line submitted as an implicit script file).

In short: in your case, the first command output's automatic display formatting also determined the display formatting for the 2nd command, so *which command comes first matters*:

- `get-date; Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership username | Select-Object name`

  - locked in implicit use of `Format-List` for all output following `Get-Date`, which explains the each-property-on-its-own line output from the `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership ...` command.
- > If i run the reverse, meaning i say get-date after the first command, the date stamp never shows up after the groups are listed.

  - `Select-Object` output instances of type `[pscustomobject]`, which, due to their having just 1 property in this case, locked in *tabular* display, i.e., implicit use of `Format-Table`, *with the selected property as the only column*, i.e., just `Name` here. Since the `[datetime]` type output by `Get-Date` doesn't have a `Name` property, `Get-Date`'s output was effectively *invisible*.

Read on for background information and the complete rules.

---

**PowerShell's default display formatting is optimized for objects of the *same* type**, as that is the typical case.

**If a pipeline contains a *mix* of types, the specific formatting that results by default depends on**:

- the *order* of objects in the pipeline
- and their default formatting behavior

See the next section for details.

**You can use explicit `Format-*` calls to control the formatting**; in your case, you can use `Format-Table` on your 2nd command to force tabular output:

```bash
Get-Date; Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership username | Select name | Format-Table
```

**Caveat**: The **output from `Format-*` cmdlets** are *formatting instructions* rather than the original data, which makes this output **unsuitable for further *programmatic processing***.

---

#### How PowerShell formats objects of different types in the same pipeline for display:

In the absence of explicit formatting commands (`Format-Table`, `Format-List`, ...), **PowerShell automatically chooses a suitable display format**, **based on a given object's *type*:**

- If present for a given type, PowerShell uses *predefined formatting instructions* (see [`Get-Help about_Format.ps1xml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about_Format.ps1xml))
- In their absence:

  - If the type is a *primitive type* (see below): the object's `.ToString()` representation is output.
  - Otherwise: the format style is chosen based on the following simple rules: 4 or fewer properties? -> `Format-Table`; 5 or more? -> `Format-List`.

Note: *Primitive* is used loosely here to refer to:

- all primitive CLR types - those for which [`.IsPrimitive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isprimitive#System_Type_IsPrimitive) returns `$true`, namely 
  `[Boolean]`, `[Byte]`, `[SByte]`, `[Int16]`, `[UInt16]`, `[Int32]`, `[UInt32]`, `[Int64]`, `[UInt64]`, `[IntPtr]`, `[UIntPtr]`, `[Char]`, `[Double]`, `[Single]`
- types `[decimal]`, `[bigint]`, and `[securestring]`
- `[string]` (strings always print as themselves, in full)
- any other *property-less* types.

If all objects in a pipeline are of the same type, the above by definition applies to all of them.

By contrast, **if there is a *mix* of types in the pipeline**, the following logic applies:

- Any instances of **primitive types *always* print and always print *the same***, namely as a representation of the *single value* that they are (not an as an object *with properties*), obtained via a call to their `.ToString()` method; e.g., `12` or `3.0` or `hi`; primitive types have no bearing on the formatting of subsequent objects in the pipeline.
- **The *first non-primitive* object** in the pipeline:

  - is itself printed based on either its predefined formatting instructions or the default rules stated above (based on the number of properties).
  - ***locks in* the format style - list vs. table - for all remaining non-primitive objects**:

    - If the object itself implicitly uses `Format-Table` or `Format-List`, so will all remaining non-primitive objects.
    - If the object implicitly uses `Format-Custom` (e.g, in the case of `Get-Date`, via predefined formatting), it is `Format-List` that is locked in.
- All subsequent non-primitive objects then use the locked-in format style.

  - **Caveat**: If **`Format-Table`** is locked in, **the first non-primitive object *alone* determines the *set of properties* displayed as table columns**:

    - **If the first non-primitive object has *no* formatting data associated with it** - which notably applies to **`[pscustomobject]`** - it
      **can cause subsequent non-primitive objects to *seemingly* disappear if they don't have these properties** - such objects are still in the output stream, however, they're just not *displayed* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45705068/45375) for a demonstration.

      - [GitHub issue #7871](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7871) proposes at least issuing a *warning* when that happens.
    - If the first non-primitive object ***has* formatting data** associated with it (as reported by [`Get-FormatData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Get-FormatData)), **all subsequent non-primitive objects of a *different type* are formatted with `Format-List`**. That is, you'll get a mix of tabular and list-style output.
    - On a side note: Since PSv5, implicit use of `Format-Table` results in asynchronous behavior that may be surprising; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43691123/45375).
  - **If it is `Format-List` that is locked in, no information is "lost"**, as each object's properties are then listed individually, on their own lines.

Comment: Very insightful answer!

Answer (score 3):

When the powershell console formatter sees objects of multiple types, it will default to outputting based on the first element output. For `Date` it output as a list, for the custom object output from `Select-Object`, it's a table. How the output is formatted depends on the type of the object itself (see help [About Format.ps1xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml?view=powershell-6)). You can force the output of `Select-Object` to be a table using `Format-Table`:

```
get-date; Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership username | Select-Object name | Format-Table
```

Comment: Any idea why running the commands in the reverse order (get-date last) does not show the date?

Comment: @PawełCzopowik I'm not sure, I think it's because the formatter has already decided that it's seeing a bunch of PSCustomObjects, so it displays as table, then it gets an object with no name attribute, so it doesn't display it.

Comment: zdan that's an interesting theory i may need to test :)

Comment: It's not the first object per se, it's the first _non-primitive_ object that locks in the formatting for the remaining non-primitive objects. `Get-Date` actually implicitly uses `Format-Custom`, which locks in (implicit) `Format-List` use for the remaining non-primitive objects.

Comment: @PawełCzopowik: zdan's guess is correct: `Select-Object` outputs instances of type `[pscustomobject]`, which, due to having 4 or fewer properties in this case, locks in _tabular_ display, with the specific properties chosen, i.e., `Name`. Since the `[datetime]` type output by `Get-Date` doesn't have a `Name` property, `Get-Date`'s output is effectively invisible.