# POWERSHELL: Transcript not working properly after format-table and new-item

Tags: powershell, logging

I can't figure out why, when running the following script, the second "write-output" does not appear in the transcript file ???

```
start-transcript -Path "c:\temp\test_transcript.txt" -Append;
    
$acl = Get-Acl "c:\temp";
$acl | Format-Table -Wrap;

Write-Output "1) A very simple message BEFORE new-item.";
New-Item -Path "C:\temp" -Name "test_file_$(get-date -f "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").txt" -ItemType File -Verbose -ErrorAction Stop;

#Why is th second message not included int the transcript log file ???
Write-Output "2) A very simple message AFTER new-item.";

Stop-Transcript;
```

Here is what I get in the transcript file :

[transcript file content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjtpU.png)

Does someone have an explanation for this ?

TRANSCRIPT FILE :

```
    Transcription démarrée, le fichier de sortie est c:\temp\test_transcript.txt
    
    
        Répertoire : C:\
    
    
    Path Owner              Access
    ---- -----              ------ temp MyDomain\MyUser BUILTIN\XXX Allow  FullControl
                            AUTORITE NT\XXX Allow  FullControl
                            BUILTIN\XXX Allow  ReadAndExecute, Synchronize
                            AUTORITE NT\XXX authentifiés Allow  Modify, Synchronize
    
    
    1) A very simple message BEFORE new-item.
EN CLAIR : Opération « Créer un fichier » en cours sur la cible « Destination : C:\temp\test_file_20230109_124005.txt ».
    
    **********************
Fin de la transcription Windows PowerShell
Heure de fin : 20230109124005
    **********************
```

CONSOLE :

```
Transcription démarrée, le fichier de sortie est c:\temp\test_transcript.txt


    Répertoire : C:\


Path Owner              Access
---- -----              ------
temp MyDomain\MyUser BUILTIN\XXX Allow  FullControl
                        AUTORITE NT\XXX Allow  FullControl
                        BUILTIN\XXX Allow  ReadAndExecute, Synchronize
                        AUTORITE NT\XXX authentifiés Allow  Modify, Synchronize


1) A very simple message BEFORE new-item.
EN CLAIR : Opération « Créer un fichier » en cours sur la cible « Destination : C:\temp\test_file_20230109_124005.txt ».


    Répertoire : C:\temp


Mode          LastWriteTime Length Name
----          ------------- ------ ----
-a---- 09/01/2023     12:40      0 test_file_20230109_124005.txt
2) A very simple message AFTER new-item.
Transcription arrêtée, le fichier de sortie est C:\temp\test_transcript.txt
```

Comment: Does the `New-Item` complete successfully? Because `-ErrorAction Stop` causes the effect you are seeing, The script stops at that point if the New-Item causes an error.

Comment: Wrap your `New-Item` in a `try{}catch{}` block, and see what shows up in  the transcript: `try { New-Item -Path "C:\temp" -Name "test_file_$(get-date -f "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").txt" -ItemType File -Verbose -ErrorAction Stop} catch {"New-Item failed!"}` - I would expect that if the `New-Item` fails, you'll see `New-Item failed!` in your transcript.

Comment: Also, just to avoid any possibility of confusion between the [`-f` operator](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html) and the `-Format` parameter of `Get-Date`, use `-For` instead of `-f` as the parameter to `Get-Date`.

Comment: Thanks. The new-item complete successfully. But I will double-check, write try/catch as you say and keep you informed.

Comment: Exact same behavior with try...catch and -For instead of -f. There are no errors but the second message does not appear. I must admit I'm lost...

Comment: @Scepticalist - the screenshot shows a footer in the file from ```Stop-Transcript``` so *presumably* the script ran to completion. I thought it *might* be something to do with the 300ms delay built into ```Format-Table``` further up the script, meaning ```Stop-Transcript``` gets called before all the output is written to transcript, but I couldn't reproduce the issue locally to test that.

Comment: Interesting : I wasn't aware of this 300ms delay : it might be an explanation. Can I insert a Start-Sleep() at the end of my script ? would that solve the problm ? Or is there some kind of flush() method ? One thing for sure : removing the format-table line solves the problem.

Comment: Smells like this known issue: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10994

Comment: Thanks @BaconBits : very interesting link. I haven't read everything yet, but it looks pretty close.

Comment: A simple workaround would be to pipe any “implicit” output to ```Out-Host``` or ```Out-String``` to make it “explicit”. .e.g. ```Write-Output … | Out-Host``` which turns it into blocking operation that will complete before the next line is called. That’ll add a lot of cruft to your code though. I don’t think ```Start-Sleep``` will work because it blocks ```Format-Table``` as far as I can remember so you’ll just be in the same position 2 seconds later. Feel free to try it and prove me wrong though :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on the helpful comments:

**tl;dr**

- **You're seeing a *bug*** (though it isn't classified as such) that is one of several manifestations of asynchronous behavior when PowerShell *implicitly* applies `Format-Table` for-display formatting.
- **Workarounds, all *suboptimal***, unfortunately:

  - ***Per-command* [cumbersome, error-prone]**: Use a `Format-*` cmdlet *explicitly* with any call that normally results in *table* formatting *by default* in order to force *synchronous* output; in your case, place `| Format-Table` after your `New-Item` call.

    - Note:

      - Using `Format-Table` prevents you from capturing a command's output *as data*, when you try to assign to a variable or process the output further in a pipeline, because what the `Format-*` cmdlets emit are *formatting instructions*, not data.
  - ***Script-wide* [introduces a 300-msec delay]**: As you've discovered, inserting a [`Start-Sleep`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/start-sleep) at the end helps, *under the following conditions*:

    - The **script must end with a command that *synchronously* outputs to the *success* output stream** (i.e. it must *not* be implicitly table-formatted), notably by outputting a *string*, such as in your `Write-Output "2) A very simple message AFTER new-item."` call. (Note that you may omit `Write-Output` to take advantage of PowerShell's implicit output  behavior).
    - **`Start-Sleep -MilliSeconds 300` must be placed *immediately before* it**, which forces the following synchronous output to also render the *pending asynchronous* output.
    - However, due to another design limitation in PowerShell's for-display output-formatting system that is separate from the asynchronous behavior (note that neither is specific to `Start-Transcript` use, but the latter *manifests* in a way that is specific to that cmdlet) there is ***general* pitfall if you *don't* use `Format-Table` calls explicitly**:

      - If the first implicitly table-formatted statement in a script uses *no* predefined formatting-data, it *locks in the display columns* for *all subsequent* implicitly table-formatted statements, which can make the latters' output effectively *invisible* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55504393/45375).
      - Per-command `Format-Table` calls avoid this problem (while also forcing *synchronous* output), at the expense of not outputting *data*, as noted above.

A simplified example:

```bash
Start-Transcript t.txt

# This triggers *implicit* Format-Table output that is *asynchronous*,
# due to the output object having 4 or fewer properties and
# its type not having formatting-data associated with, as with the
# Get-Acl output in your question.
# NOTE:
#  * Curiously, the asynchronous behavior is also triggered in this case
#    if you append | Format-Table, but only affects SUBSEQUENT 
#    implicitly table-formatted statements, including those whose 
#    output types DO have formatting-data.
[pscustomobject] @{ Foo = 'Bar' }

# WORKAROUND:
#  Sleep for 300 msecs., then output *synchronously* to the success output stream.
#  This forces pending asynchronous table output to print. 
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 300
"==== Done."

Stop-Transcript
```

---

You're seeing another manifestation of the infamous 300-msec. delay that occurs when `Format-Table` formatting is *implicitly* applied to output that goes to the display - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43691123/45375) for details.

While the typical manifestation is that output appears *out of order* (across different output streams), in your case information is *lost*, which is obviously a more serious problem. Data loss can also occur with the PowerShell CLI. See the GitHub issues below.

Relevant **GitHub issues**:

- [GitHub issue #10994](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10994): the problem at hand ([`Start-Transcript`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/start-transcript)-related).

  - The unfortunate **conclusion appears to be that this will *not* be fixed**.
- [GitHub issue #4594](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4594): discussion of the *surprising asynchronous behavior* in general (output appearing out of order).
- [GitHub issue #13985](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13985): *potential data loss* when using the CLI.

Comment: Great answer ! I ended up adding a line "Start-Sleep -Seconds 1;" before my last call to write-output. Surely not the msot elegant solution, but this avoids the need to put "| format-table" after every non-string object. Plus 1s delay at the end of the script is no big deal in my context. Thanks for all the help !