# Powershell, combine output of a foreach loop with multiple commands

Tags: powershell, foreach, output

I need to get a list of properties for multiple server, but I'm stuck with the output of second command in my loop:

```
$(foreach ( $Net in $Nets ) {
Get-NetAdapterBinding -ComponentID  ms_msclient,ms_server,ms_tcpip6 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | select Name,DisplayName,Enabled
Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty $Net -DisplayName "Speed & Duplex" | select DisplayValue
}) | Format-List
```

The output of first cmd is correct:

```
Name        : LAN_Clients
DisplayName : Internet Protocol Version 6 (TCP/IPV6)
Enabled     : False

Name        : LAN_Clients
DisplayName : File and Print Sharing
Enabled     : False

Name        : LAN_Clients
DisplayName : Client for Microsoft Networks
Enabled     : False
```

The second cmd seems ignored...
If I run cmd manually the output is correct:

```
Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty "LAN_Clients" -DisplayName "Speed & Duplex" | select DisplayValue
    
DisplayValue
------------
Auto Negotiation
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you just run the selection over `$Net`, and ensure a name is actually being passed to it?

Comment: Oh wait, youre running it inside the `foreach`.

Comment: @Abraham Zinala, yes Abraham `$Nets = get-NetAdapter`

Comment: If you explicitly pipe to `Format-List`, all output should show. With default output (implied `Format-Table`), the first output object locks in all output columns based on _its_ properties, so the `DisplayValue` property from the 2nd command never shows - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45705068/45375).

Comment: @mklement0, im confused in regards to this. One, I wasn't aware you could reference a command inside of the `foreach`; guess that's cool, unless you have some more insight on regards to how that works. Two, if that does work, its not piping the correct value to `Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty`, or a specific one in this case.

Comment: @mklement0 Correct! Now I've removed format-list but second cmd still ignored

Comment: It isn't _ignored_, its output is just not _displayed_ - see the previously linked answer for a detailed explanation and workarounds.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala, I'm not sure I fully understand, but you can place any command or expression inside a `foreach` block, and whatever these constructs output becomes the `foreach` statement's overall output. The problem is merely a _display_ problem, due to how (implicitly applied) `Format-Table` formatting works; again, see the previously linked answer.

Comment: @Theo, sorry Theo for the delay, now I've done! Bye!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to call `Get-NetAdapter`, as `Get-NetAdapterBinding` already returns all the bindings for all the adapters.

In the foreach loop, you're not using the `-Name` parameter with `Get-NetAdapterBinding` so it's returning all the bindings for all your adapters every iteration of the loop.

You can use an expression block in `Select-Object` to get the additional duplex property you're after, like this:

```
Get-NetAdapterBinding -ComponentID  ms_msclient,ms_server,ms_tcpip6 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    Select-Object Name,DisplayName,Enabled, @{Name = 'Speed & Duplex'; Expression={Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -InterfaceAlias $_.InterfaceAlias -DisplayName 'Speed & Duplex' | select -ExpandProperty DisplayValue }} |
    Format-List
```

Comment: Thank you antonyoni! Now I've to learn how to output all the properties per each nic, without print the same list 4 times, one for each properties!

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine both outputs into a single object.

Try

```
$(foreach ( $Net in $Nets ) {
    $speed = (Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty $Net -DisplayName "Speed & Duplex").DisplayValue
    Get-NetAdapterBinding -ComponentID  ms_msclient,ms_server,ms_tcpip6 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |   
    Select-Object Name,DisplayName,Enabled,
                  @{Name = 'Speed & Duplex'; Expression = {$speed}}
}) | Format-List
```

Comment: Hi Theo, in this mode the `Speed & Duplex` is printed out but it's blank for each `$net`

Answer (score 0):

For troubleshooting purposes, try this:

```
$Nets = Get-NetAdapterBinding -ComponentID  ms_msclient,ms_server,ms_tcpip6 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    foreach ($Net in $Nets.name ) {
Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty $Net -DisplayName "Speed & Duplex" | select DisplayValue
}
```