# Why does assigning true to variable it will not evaluate true?

Tags: powershell, boolean, boolean-expression

```
$test = true
if($test) {
  Write-Output "true"
} else {
  Write-Output "false"
}
```

Output is "false", but why? I assign `true` and `false` to COM object properties and it appears to work correctly... Am I doing something wrong? When is it appropriate to use `true` vs `$true` in PowerShell?

Edit: Some users have mentioned that I should be seeing an error but I don't. I've tried in both PowerShell 2.0 (Windows 7) and PowerShell 4.0 (Windows 8.1). And `true` and `false` do change the COM properties like I said.

Edit: It turns out what was happening was we were assigning `true` to COM properties but they actually received false. We have the gnuwin32 programs in our path and two of those programs are true and false:

```
C:\gnuwin32\bin\true.EXE
C:\gnuwin32\bin\false.EXE
```

**So on those computers something like `$x = true` runs the command `C:\gnuwin32\bin\true.EXE` which has no output and `$x` is null. Nobody ever figured this out, that the com properties intended to be set true were not actually set that way.**

The answer marked correct explains "truthy" and that the value was actually a null value which is what helped me figure it out.

Comment: `$test = $true`

Comment: Thanks, I know that works but I want to know about the difference between the two and why `true` doesn't. We have a lot of code that does `$something = true` and I need to understand the pitfalls of that.

Comment: But the first line gives an error `The term 'true' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet (...)`. Perhaps you used `$test = 'true'`?

Comment: If you _don't_ see an exception, check what's the value of `$ErrorActionPreference`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the question is *why* it happens, let me dig into details in my answer

---

`if($test)` checks for something called *truthy*. Basically, it converts the result of the expression to the boolean value and then check if it's true or false. You can read more about this [in that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46592939/9902555).

In your case, as [Martin Brandl mentioned in his helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58298643/9902555), trying to assign `$test = true` will (in most cases) result in exception but **the code continues to be executed**.

> **NOTE**: The statement in **bold** is not always true as it depends on [`$ErrorActionPreferrence`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-use-erroractionpreference-to-control-cmdlet-handling-of-errors/) but in your case it's true as you mentioned that you receive the output.

After the assignment fails, the value of `$test` is `$null` - you can check it by:

```
$test -eq $null
```

`$null` is falsey value so the expression in your `if()` evaluates to `$false` and the code after `else` keyword is executed, hence the `False` in your output.

Comment: In my versions of Powershell that assignment does NOT cause an error or exception. `($test).gettype()` and `(true).gettype()` both return _You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression._ Executing `true` by itself does nothing. Random text causes an error, like `$test = foo` is an error. I tried in Windows 10 powershell though and `$test = true` does cause an error and `true` is not recognized.

Comment: @newguy that means there's something (for example function) called `true` recognized by your PowerShell. Anyway, it's return value is still falsey (probably `$null`) so the rest of my answer should be valid.

Comment: it was because we have a true.exe and false.exe in the path and neither had any output so `$x = true` did not cause an error but was not true. I marked your answer as correct and updated my question to explain this in an edit at the end. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You first line `$test = true` will probably throw the following exception (except your `$ErrorActionPreference` is set to *SilentlyContinue*):

```
true : The term 'true' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:9
+ $test = true
+         ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (true:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

If you wan't to `$test` to be a boolean with the value 1 (true), then you have to assign it like this:
`$test = $true`.

**Why is the output 'false'?**

As mentioned, `$test = true` will throw an exception thus `$test` is not declared / defined. I would recommend you to set `$ErrorActionPreference` to either *Continue* or *Stop* to catch these types of errors.

Comment: It was set to Continue. I set it to Stop but there was no difference, I do not see an error. I'm using Powershell 2.0 (Windows 7) but I've observed the same in 4.0 (Windows 8.1).

Answer (score 0):

Unix "true" and "false" commands are different than powershell $true and $false.  The unix ones only set an exit code, but give no output.  The powershell variables give a boolean output.  Here's a workaround that tests the exit code of the previous command:

```
$test = $(true.exe; $?) # $test gets set to boolean True
if($test) {
  Write-Output "true"
} else {
  Write-Output "false"
}
```